# Delphi 10.4 localization issues

Tags: delphi, localization, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm trying Delphi 10.4. Localizing Windows applications was working like a charm in the past, but now when I dynamically load the RC DLL file, it only changes RCDATA, and not the "String Table" any more.

I was using this code (as quick resume)

```
NewInst := LoadLibraryEx(FileName, 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE); 
....
CurModule.ResInstance := NewInstance;
```

`FileName` is the DLL file that has the resources (RCDATA and "String Table") that I could edit with "Resource Hacker" software, and can see that it contains "String table" Inside as expected.

It works fine for RCDATA (all forms are getting translated) but not "String table" anymore that is contained into `Resourcestring` section of any `.pas` file, and all string remains in the original language.

It was working fine in previous Delphi version (like 10.2) and I do not know why it fails with this version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another solution. Disable the new caching by assigning LoadResStringFunc to nil. A good place to do that is in the beginning of the program.

```
begin
>>> ADD THIS to disable the caching
  LoadResStringFunc := nil;
>>>
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Comment: Pity it makes resourcestring handling lot slower. But I agree that it works.

Comment: It is slower compared to the new implementation but equally fast compared to Delphi version prior 10.4.1

Answer (score 3):

**Core problem**
The problem is that resourcestrings are cached now, and you do not have access to clear the cache after you loaded new resource data :(

See https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-30853
(and drop a vote if you think it has to be fixed)

**Work-around**
I "Cloned" the resourcestring caching mechanism into a separate unit and re-routed `LoadResStringFunc` to my cloned unit. Here I allow access to the resstringcache, and thus can clear it after loading the new resource.

Comment: “*resource strings are cached how*” - sadly, this is not mentioned anywhere in the 10.4 documentation, or in the list of QP tickets addressed in 10.4. Seems a pretty big change to not mention to users who localize their apps.

Comment: I think it was a bad idea to not create the resourcestring caching mechanism in a separate unit in the first place. If they did, Emb would have found out this issue by itself. I think.

Comment: A change like this should have been done in a major version change, not in minor. Now there is no good way to adapt your code to be compatible with both 10.4 and 10.4.1 because the compiler version is the same.

Comment: @Jaska indeed. Not in `RTLVersion` and also not in `Compilerversion`. sigh.